# Topology induced by the Euclidean metric

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space, then $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So, is the Euclidean metric defined by $d(x,y)= ||(\lambda_i)-(\gamma_i) ||$ where $\lambda_i$ and $\gamma_i$ are the coefficients?

In this case, if $(V,\tau)$ is a topological vector space then the linear map $id: (V,\tau_d) \rightarrow (V,\tau)$ is continuous because $(V,\tau_d)$ is Hausdorff and finite dimensional and finally the topology induced by the Euclidean metris $ \tau_d$ is at least as fine as $\tau$ ?

Am I right?

Thanks!

Comment: No, the coefficient stuff used to define a metric is wrong.

Comment: How is defined the Euclidean metric? I am confused.

Comment: For vectors v,w, d(v,w) = ||v - w||.

Comment: Yes, but $v$ and $w$ are in $V$. So $d(v,w)$ is the norm of their coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Let V be a normed vector space with norm n:V -> R.
The norm induces a metric for V, d(u,v) = n(u - v).
The topology Td, induced by the norm metric cannot be
compared to other topologies making V a TVS.

That is because V with the discrete topology
Tdis and V with the indiscrete are both TVS's.

Notice that the map id:(V,Td) -> (V,Tdis) is not continuous.

In the event, as is common, a TVS is defined to also
be Hausdorff, then for the TVS V with topology T
if id:(V,T) -> (V,Td) is continuous, then T is finer than Td.

Comment: It should be $d(f(x),f(y)) = || x-y ||$. But what about the topologies?

Comment: Then use f$^{-1}$.   Metrics generate topologies.

Comment: What about the topologies?

Comment: It is the topology generated by the metric or the norm.

Comment: I mean the second question. Is the topology generated by the metric at least  as fine as another topology $\tau$  , where $(V,\tau)$ is a t.v.s. ?

Comment: @DiegoCornejoKoc.  See revision of my answer.

Comment: Space $V$ is not a t.v.s with the discrete topology otherwise $V=\{0\}$.

Comment: @DiegoCornejoKoc.  Prove it.

Comment: If $x, y \in V$ , the map $f:[0,1]\rightarrow  V $ with $f(\lambda) = \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y$ is a path  between $x$ and $y$. So $V$ is path connected. If $x\neq y $ are in $V$, $\{ x \}  $ and $y\in \{x\}^c \neq \emptyset$ are open sets with union $V$.